# Webpack.Mix won't compile image urls from Vue components for production

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, vue.js

I want to compile `image urls` from `resources/images` dir to `public/images` dir  for production (`npm run prod`) but the only way I've been able to do so is to compile them from `css` files.

[Compile Assets Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix) says that:

1. Only `urls` inside `css` files will be compiled
2. To enable compilation for `vue` components, I need to add `.vue()` at the end of `mix.js()` inside `webpack.mix.js`

This is my `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', []).vue();
```

but no images inside of `vue` components are being compiled. I **have** to put the `urls` inside `css` to make it work. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Copying the image to `public/images` seems counterintuitive to what you're attempting to achieve. Out of the box, using `<img src="../relative../path/to/my/image"/>` should make sure that it's available in production.

Comment: Thanks, I had a problem with my paths. Relative paths weren't even working. Now they work and the images get compiled properly